# Having problems with div columns

Tags: html, css-float, center, multiple-columns

i want 3 columns with the same width.

i did succeed by use divs.
i made 2 divs in a div, then made another div in one of the two divs and then used css float left & right.

but was wondering if there was a different and better way? (no tables, i tried doing this without tables)
because i had trouble centering texts that were next to a image

and because i used float the white  background disappears in the area where the columns were.

could someone help me either fix the problems i'm having or giving me a alternative method.

Comment: See also [grid frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/what-is-the-best-css-grid-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your question. But I make a solution. Here's my demo on Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/asubanovsky/8d3m9/

HTML:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='first'>First</div>
    <div id='second'>Second</div>
    <div id='third'>Third</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#first, #second, #third{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#first{
    background-color: #222;
}

#second{
    background-color: #444;
}

#third{
    background-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: thanks for for your help, this method worked. sorry if i confused you, it was my first question here and i'm still learning.

could you help with a different problem.
in these div columns i have 3 <a><img> (link images) with prices.

but the prices are under the image, i want them to be shown next to the image and centered in the middle.

is there a tag for this or do need to make more column divs?

Comment: Would you please post it as another question? Thanks! I would gladly try to help you.. :)

Comment: @user3236466 Check out the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/asubanovsky/UcBtq/) that I made for you. I'm using table but that's not the only way. Get more practices and you'll find out several approaches that can be applied.. :)

Comment: your method seems good too, just to hear your opinion, what is the best method to create columns, tables or div? 

i was told by my teacher that its best to use divs.

Comment: To make a website layout, it's best to use divs. Only use tables when you want to display data in columns and rows. Trust me, use tables to make website layout is troublesome. It's not efficient nor flexible.

Comment: ok, i'll keep it that in mind, and again thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
    height:200px;
    width: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```